# Paytm Integration Error For Android With Gradle

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle, implementation, paytm

when I paste the below line to the ‘dependencies’ section of app build.gradle ,

```
implementation'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.4’
```

It shows the below error code:

```
startup failed:


build file 'C:\Users\Hoot\AndroidStudioProjects\\app\build.gradle': 64: expecting ''', found '\r' @ line 64, column 56.
   appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.4’
                                 ^

1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your project-level gradle file:

```
maven {
    url "https://artifactory.paytm.in/libs-release-local"
}
```

Then this to your app-level gradle file:

```
implementation'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just copy and paste the following:

```
implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.4'
```

Look carefully you will notice that the closing quote is different from the opening in your code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out. We are getting it corrected on the developer documentation as well.
The last character in this line is wrong. It should be

implementation 'com.paytm.appinvokesdk:appinvokesdk:1.5'